# Python - subprocess.Popen not returning output

Tags: python, linux, windows-7

I am using a Windows 7 machine right now have have STS installed with PyDev utility for python development.

My code wants to login to a machine and return the output. My current code is:

```
        ssh = subprocess.Popen(["uname -a"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        print (ssh)
        result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
        print (result)
```

This yileds an output of :

```
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x02B35810>
[]
```

But the `uname -a` command should yield `Linux 3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Feb 20 02:37:52 EST 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Any idea why I cant capture the output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `uname` with command/args properly split in a list like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(["uname","-a"] ...
```

or quick&dirty in a string like this (you have to handle quoting, but here there's none):

```
subprocess.Popen("uname -a", ...
```

but not like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(["uname -a"] ...
```

else the actual issued command is `"uname -a"` (literally). Of course, it doesn't exist, which should throw an exception, but since you're using `shell=True` it doesn't since it runs the nonexisting command in a shell (which exists, so `subprocess` doesn't complain)

that's one of the numerous reasons why you shouldn't throw `shell=True` in without being absolutely forced to (for instance to run a shell internal command)

Checking the error stream (using `result = ssh.stderr.readlines()`) would reveal something like `"uname -a": command not found`

Note that using `PIPE` for both output and error streams may lead to deadlock unless you're using `ssh.communicate()` to handle streams in separate threads internally.

My suggestion for your problem would simply to use `check_output` as you don't need to run the command in background, you just need its output:

```
result = subprocess.check_output(["uname","-a"])
```

(which is slightly different because it doesn't create lines but a sole buffer, that you can easily apply `strip`/`splitline` onto)

Note that if you're looking for a portable way to get system type or platform, I recommend you the `os` module (`os.name` yields `nt` for windows for instance) and the `platform` module, where you can get system architecture, linux distribution, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. This does indeed work if I run this on a Linux machine. But I am currently developing on the STS IDE in  Windows. I get the error
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: that's already better. The explanation is simple: `uname` doesn't exist in windows unless you've installed cygwin or MSYS. If you want to know the OS & platform, I recommend you the portable `platform` module.

Comment: Sorry i did not mention the whole command that I was running. Its `result = subprocess.check_output(["ssh", "172.29.219.16","uname"])` . This still gives the same error. The target node is a Linux system.

Comment: that's the same issue: `ssh` does not exist on windows. So you have to look for portable ssh module like `paramiko`